# Distinction between the capacity of an array list and the size of an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I read the below snippet in Core Java I book.

> Allocating an array list as
>   **new ArrayList <'Employee>(100) // capacity is 100**
>
> is not the same as allocating a new array as
>   **new Employee[100] // size is 100**
>
> There is an important distinction between the capacity of an array list and the size of an
>   array. If you allocate an array with 100 entries, then the array has 100 slots, ready for use.
>   An array list with a capacity of 100 elements has the potential of holding 100 elements (and,
>   in fact, more than 100, at the cost of additional reallocations); but at the beginning, even
>   after its initial construction, an array list holds no elements at all.

When I saw the source code array list, the constructor creates of an Object array of given capacity which is ready to hold elements of given capacity (below is the code snippet).

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
     super();
     if (initialCapacity < 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                            initialCapacity);
     this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
 }
```

I am not able to figure out the actual difference what the author has mentioned in above text.

Comment: What don't you understand about _An array list with a capacity of 100 elements has the potential of holding 100 elements (and, in fact, more than 100, at the cost of additional reallocations); but at the beginning, even after its initial construction, an array list holds no elements at all._?

Comment: How it is different from arrays of size 100??. Both are capable of holding 100 elements. If arraylist holds no elements in the beginning, then arrays also does not hold any element in the beginning

Comment: In an array, you can do `array[whateverIndex] = new MyObject();` while in `ArrayList` you can only do `arrayList.add(new MyObject());` or `arrayList.set(indexBelowAarrayListSize, new MyObject());`.

Comment: look at the source of `add` in `ArrayList`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you allocate a new array with `arr = new Employee[100]`, the size of that array (`arr.length`) is going to be 100. It has 100 elements. All the elements are initially null (as this is an array of object references), but still, there are 100 elements.

If you do something like `list = new ArrayList <Employee>(100)`, and try to check `list.size()`, you'll get 0. There are no elements in the list.

Internally, it's true that the `ArrayList` allocates enough place to put 100 items before it needs to extend its capacity, but that's an internal implementation detail, and the list presents its content to you as "no items stored". Only if you actually do `list.add(something)`, you'll have items in the list.

So although the list allocates storage in advance, the API with which it communicates with the program tells you there are no items in it. The null items in its internal array are not available to you - you cannot retrieve them or change them.

Comment: But what really happens with line elements = new Object[initialCapacity]. Does it not create Object array with all elements set to null as it happens with normal Object array creation.

Comment: It does, but those elements are not available to you, the user of the ArrayList. The difference is not in the amount of memory allocated. It's in the things you can or cannot do with an array list vs. an array.

Comment: I am a little late here, but we can think of capacity is the initial internal memory/storage allocation/reservation for the list and size is the actual number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 7):

An ArrayList is just one way to represent an abstract list, and the capacity of an ArrayList is an implementation detail of how the system implements the logical list.

An ArrayList stores the elements of a list by using an actual array "under the covers."  The actual realization of the array in computer memory has a certain size when it is allocated; this size is the ArrayList's capacity.  The ArrayList emulates a variable-sized list by storing the logical length of the list in addition to the fixed-length array.  Thus if you have an ArrayList with a capacity 10 which contains 4 logical elements, the ArrayList can be represented as a length and an array

(4)
| e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | __ | __ | __| __ | __ | __ |

where the (4) is the logical length of the list and '__' represent data that is ignored because it is not part of the logical list.  If you attempt to access the 5th element of this ArrayList, it will throw an exception because it knows that the fifth element has not been initialized.  If we then append an extra element e5 to the list, the ArrayList becomes

(5)
| e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | e5 | __ | __ | __ | __ | __ |

Note that the capacity has not changed, while the logical length has, because the underlying array is still able to handle all the data in the logical list.

If you manage to add more than ten elements to this list, the ArrayList will not break.  The ArrayList is an abstraction meant to be compatible with all array operations.  Rather, the ArrayList changes its capacity when its logical length exceeds its original capacity.  If we were to add the elements (a1, a2, ..., a7) to the above list, the resulting ArrayList might look like

(12)
| e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | e5 | a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 | a7 | __ | __ | __ | __ | __ | __ | __ | __ |

with a capacity of 20.

Once you have created an ArrayList, you can ignore the capacity in all programming that follows; the logic is unaffected.  However, the performance of the system under certain kinds of operations can be affected.  Increasing the capacity, for instance, might well involved allocating a larger array, copying the first array into the second and then performing the operations.  This can be quite slow compared to, e.g. the same operation on a linked list.  Thus it is sensible to choose the capacity of an ArrayList to be bigger than, or at least comparable to, the actual number of elements expected in the real runtime environment.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have a length, which is specified at creation and cannot be altered.

If you create a new array `myArray = new Object[100]` then you can read and write from `myArray[0]` to `myArray[99]` (and you'll find it full of `null`).

Lists, on the other hand, have a `size()` that starts at zero and grows when you add items. The `size()` of a list tracks how many things you have actually put in it, rather than how much space it has.

If you create a list using `myList = new ArrayList(100)` and then you try and `get` or `set` any elements, you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because the the list is empty until you `add` something to it.

In summary, the array of size 100 will initially hold 100 nulls, but the list will be empty.

Comment: But Arraylist internally create array of object by defult size=10; so why arraylist remains empty and get an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 2):

This just seems poorly worded and potentially incorrect if I'm not understanding it correctly.

I believe what it is trying to say is that there is a difference between the initial capacity of the ArrayList and the initial size of the ArrayList.

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(100);
int size = employes.size();
```

*size* will be 0 while the initial capacity is 100.

You are correct with how you are reading the source code.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is between a *fixed size* container (data structure) and a *variable size* container.

An *array* is a *fixed size* container, the number of elements it holds is established when the array is created and never changes. (When the array is created all of those elements will have some default value, e.g., null for reference types or 0 for ints, but they'll all be there in the array: you can index each and every one.)

A *list* is a *variable size* container, the number of elements in it can change, ranging from 0 to as many as you want (subject to implementation limits).  After creation the number of elements can either grow or shrink.  At all times you can retrieve any element by its index.

But the Java concept `List` is actually an interface and it can be implemented in many different ways.  Thus, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.  There is a data structure "behind" the list to actually hold the elements.  And that data structure itself might be fixed size or variable size, and at any given time might have the exact size of the number of elements in the list, or it might have some `extra` "buffer" space.

The `LinkedList`, for example, always has in its underlying data structure exactly the same number of "places for elements" as are in the list it is representing.  But the `ArrayList` uses a fixed length array as its backing store.

For the `ArrayList`, at any given time the number of elements in the list might be different than the number of elements the array behind it can hold.  Those "extra" places for elements just contain nulls or 0s or whatever, but the `ArrayList` never gives you access to those places.  As you add elements to the `ArrayList` they take up more places in the underlying array, until finally the underlying array is full.  The *next* element you add to the `ArrayList` causes an entirely new fixed size array - somewhat bigger than the "current" array - to be allocated, and all the list elements copied to it (the original array is discarded).  To prevent this expensive operation (allocation and copy) from happening too often the new array is larger than the current array (by some factor) and thus has elements which will not at that time hold elements of the list - they're empty (null or 0).

So, because there is (potentially) a difference between the number of elements in the list being represented, and the number of elements the implementing data structure can hold there are *two* concepts in force.

The **size** of the list is the number of elements in it.  The **capacity** of the list is the number of elements the backing data structure can hold *at this time*.  The size will change as elements are added to or removed from the list.  The capacity will change when the implementation of the list you're using needs it to.  (The size, of course, will never be bigger than the capacity.)

(BTW, for fixed size containers the *size* is frequently called **length**, thus arrays have a property *length* and strings have a method **length()**.  Different languages - sometimes even the same language - use "size" and "length" inconsistently, but they always mean **size**, and the term "capacity" is always used for the size/length of the underlying data structure.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a real life example. 
Consider an eighteen-seater bus, the capacity is eighteen passengers. The size of the passengers at any given time can be less than eighteen but not more than. When the number of passengers is eighteen, another passenger can't be accommodated.

In an ArrayList, the capacity has something in common with that of our bus in that it defines the number of elements that can fit in. Unlike our bus however, the capacity expands to accommodate the number of elements until Integer.MAX_VALUE.

The same goes for the size, just like our bus, the size of the elements in the list cannot exceed the capacity. Just imagine when 50 passengers are riding an eighteen-seater bus! You sure don't want to be in that bus.

Answer (score 0):

1. ArrayList is a dynamic array implementation of the List interface.
   We do not have to worry about the size of the ArrayList when we add
   elements to it.
2. It grows automatically as we add the elements to it and resizes the underlying array 
   accordingly.
3. The size of this internal array is the capacity of the ArrayList.
4. When the internal array is full and we try to add an element to the
   ArrayList, a new array is created with more capacity and all existing array items are 
   copied to it.

**Example:**
ArrayList aListNumbers = new ArrayList(20);

Will create an ArrayList object with an initial capacity of 20. 
That means the ArrayList will be able to hold 20 elements before it needs to resize the internal array.