# Output ArrayList has size of zero

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
private static List<Integer> parseStringArrayList(List<String> input) {
    System.out.println(input.size());
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>(input.size());
    for (int index = 0; index < output.size(); index++) {
        output.set(index, Integer.parseInt(input.get(index)));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The output always has a size of zero.

Help?

Comment: TYPO : Change `index < output.size()` to `index < input.size()`

Comment: This is where using your debugger should have helped.

Comment: @Eran But output was initialized with a size of 3, so shouldn't output.size() == input.size()?

Comment: @Andre No, the capacity of output was initialized to `input.size()`, the size remains 0 until you add elements to the List.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What I don't understand is why when output is initialized with input.size(), its size isn't equivalent to what it was initialized with.

Comment: @Eran So capacity != size?

Comment: @Andre Nope. Capacity is the size of the backing array. size is the number of elements actually stored in the List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the Arraylist with size will not set the size of the arraylist, the size will only be modified for adding or removing elements. the capacity which represents the number of nodes the list can have before allocating the memory is what you actually defined.

```
private static List<Integer> parseStringArrayList(List<String> input) {
System.out.println(input.size());
List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>(input.size());
for (int index = 0; index < input.size(); index++) {
    output.add( Integer.parseInt(input.get(index)));
}
return output;
}
```

while you are adding and incrementing you can use add instead , in your case will do the same thing.
and you want to add the content of the input so you better put ur limit to input.size()

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for ArrayList, there is a distinction between capacity and size:
[Distinction between the capacity of an array list and the size of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946920/distinction-between-the-capacity-of-an-array-list-and-the-size-of-an-array)

```
new ArrayList(5).size() != new int[5].length
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Eran mentioned what you are doing wrong, i would like to suggest an other way to implement the parseStringArray method.

```
private static List<Integer> parseStringArrayList(List<String> input) 
{
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String data : input) {
        output.add(Integer.parseInt(data));
    }
    return output;
}
```