# ArrayList.size() returns size of field, not the size of the List, why?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, size

I have an ArrayList < Entity >, where Entity is an object with 5 fields. Now, if I want to iterate over the LIST, ArrayList.size() returns 5, although the List is certainly longer than 1000, which I already checked by counting the times an Entity is added to the ArrayList. 
Can anybody help me?

Entity is just an object with 5 fields with getters and setters:

```
public class Entity{
private String FirstField;
...
private String FithField;
}
```

Than I add Entities to my ArrayList:

```
final ArrayList<Entity> EntityArray = new ArrayList<Entity>();
for(certain range){
Entity E = new Entity;
E = SomeFunctionWithEntityOutput();
EntityArray.add(E);
}
```

And then the size() method returns 5:

```
EntityArray.size()
```

Is that better?

Greets!

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Provide your code please... This description is just not enough for quick help!

Comment: Without you showing us your code it's hard to say anything here. The `size` method should always return the size of the `ArrayList` so I would assume an error from your side and the list actually having that size.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that there is a difference between **size** and **capacity**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946920/distinction-between-the-capacity-of-an-array-list-and-the-size-of-an-array

Comment: Alright, sorry!

Comment: And what's `certain range`?   How about showing the _real_ code, in the form of a minimal, verifiable complete example.

Comment: please post code that passes compilation.

Comment: Look, the answer is simple.  If `size()` returns 5, then the number of  things you've added to  the list is 5.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Note, you don't need the size of the arraylist to iterate over it. You can simply do

```
for (Entity e : myList){
    //Do stuff with e
}
```

If you do need the index and hence need to call `.size()`, please post some sample code so someone can see what's going wrong.

Comment: How does this in any way answer the question? They are not asking for ways to iterate over a List, it's completely off-topic, sorry.

Comment: lol it's not "completely off-topic". He said "if I want to iterate over the LIST", so I'm giving him a quick solution

Comment: But the problem is not that they want to know how to iterate over a list but why their `size()`-method is not returning the expected value. You are suggesting ignoring the problem and using another mechanism in order to get a different results. That's not helpful. It does not solve the problem. It's not an answer.

Comment: sure it was. it was more helpful than anyone else's comment right out of the box. plus he would know another way to solve the problem if he didn't know already. it's unfortunate that you see it as "not helpful" or as "not an answer". but whatever, hope it helps him in some way

Comment: Thanks anyway! I can use this as well!

Comment: @Pabiloh You will still have the wrong size in your program. This approach works, but in this case it hides the actual problem (of having less list entries than expected).

Comment: @mave_rick Read the question's title. Then read your answer. Does it answer the question? No.