# How do I use while loop with arrays that are user input

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, user-input

I just started learning Java and I need help on how to modify the program so that the array size is taken as a user input while using a while loop to validate the input so that invalid integers are rejected.

Also, using a while loop, take keyboard inputs and assign values to each array position.

I would appreciate any help!

Here is the code:

```
double salaries[]=new double[3];
salaries[0] = 80000.0;
salaries[1] = 100000.0;
salaries[2] = 70000.0;

    int i = 0;
while (i < 3) {

        System.out.println("Salary at element " + i + " is $" + salaries[i]);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to use the while loop and take input from user Please refer below code you will understand how to take input from user and how while loop works. put all code in your `main()` function and import the `import java.util.Scanner;` and execute it and do modification to understand code.

```
   Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in); // this will help to initialize the key board input

            System.out.println("Enter the array element");
            int N;
            N= sc.nextInt(); // take the keyboard input from user 
            System.out.println("Enter the "+ N + " array element ");
            int i =0;
            double salaries[]=new double[N]; // take the array lenght as the user wanted to enter
            while (i<N) { // this will  get exit as soon as i is greater than number of elements from user
                salaries[i]=sc.nextDouble();
                i++; // increment value of i so that it will store in next  array element
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

On java if you specific he array size, you can not change it,so you need to know array size before adding any value, but you can you use on of the List implementation  like `ArrayList` to be able to add values without caring about the array size.

Example :

```
   List<Double> salarie = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
        while (i<N) { // this will  get exit as soon as i is greater than number of elements from user
            salarie.add(sc.nextDouble());
            i++; // increment value of i so that it will store in next  array 
        }
```

please read these articles for more details :
  [difference-between-array-vs-arraylist](http://www.java67.com/2012/12/difference-between-array-vs-arraylist-java.html) 
 
[distinction-between-the-capacity-of-an-array-list-and-the-size-of-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946920/distinction-between-the-capacity-of-an-array-list-and-the-size-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Scanner class for taking input from user

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of elements");
int n=sc.nextInt();
double salaries[]=new double[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   salaries[i]=sc.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve using `for` loop and use `Scanner` class which is used to take input from keybord.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the length of array you want");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = scanner.nextInt();
        double salaries[]=new double[length];
        System.out.println("Please enter "+ length+" values");
        for(int i=0;i<length; i++){
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            salaries[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```