# IndexofBoundsException is thrown when initializing array of List<E>

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to Java and have below code.

```
List<List<TreeNode>> dp = new ArrayList<List<TreeNode>>(N + 1);
System.out.println(dp.isEmpty());

for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    dp.set(i, new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
}
```

dp.isEmpty() returns true;
and I have Java.lang.IndexofBoundsException for line dp.set()...

I thought after new.. the dp already has N+1 entries, but it turned out wrong....dp is still empty..

so How can populate dp with N+1 arraylist

Comment: what is `N` here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946920/distinction-between-the-capacity-of-an-array-list-and-the-size-of-an-array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing `new ArrayList<List<TreeNode>>(N + 1);`, this is telling java that create `arraylist` with initial size of `N  + 1` elements.

As arraylist is dynamically increases as you add elements this number increases also internally.

Here, `N+1` does not mean there are `N+1` elements in the `List`, it just means `N+1` memory is allocated by the `List`.

To add elements you need to do as follows,

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
    dp.add(i, new ArrayList<TreeNode>());
}

System.out.println(dp.isEmpty()); // false here
```